# Knocking 'at' vs. Knocking 'on'

Tags: prepositions

Which is more natural and why: ***'knocking on the door'*** or ***'knocking at the door'***?

And which is grammatically correct?

Comment: As a very general rule, I would say that I am knocking on the door, while I hear someone else knocking at the door. Not a hard and fast rule, but an example of the difference.

Comment: Gun's N' Roses uses ***on*** in their song [Knocking on Heavens Door](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tmc8rJgxUI). You can take a look at this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knock+at%2Cknock+on%2C+knocked+at%2C+knocked+on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknock%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknock%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknocked%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknocked%20on%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 4):

When someone is "knocking on the door" they are striking it (with their knuckles or with the door knocker) to produce the sound.

When someone is "knocking at the door" there is the added nuance that someone is *presently standing by the door* and knocking on it.

**at** conveys the notion of *presence-there*.

**There's someone *at the* customer service *window*, complaining about cheaply made products.**

Comment: As nobody can knock on a door without being standing by it, in practice both mean the same and are used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

English uses 'on' for various relationships, including 'physically touching', even the if the surface being touched is vertical.  Compare 'picture ON the wall'.